# htaccess redirect .htm to .html if former not exists and latter does

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I would like to set up these redirects:

- `file` -> `file.html`
- `file.htm` -> `file.html`
- `file.php` -> `file.html`

However these redirects should only happen if the former does not exist and the latter does. Here is what I have so far.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.htm$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{THE_TARGET_URL} -f # <----------- how to do this?
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm$ $1.html [L,R]
```

*I would like to use [clean urls](http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI.html). However in the meantime, I am switching to Jekyll which does [not yet support that](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/156). When Jekyll does get this support, I will be redirecting again in the other direction.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)(?:\.(?:htm|php))?$ /$1.html [L,NC,R=302]
```

`%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.html` will make sure corresponding `.html` file exists before executing the `RewriteRule`.

Comment: about testing... The `NC` flag in the condition results yields a mention of `RewriteCond: NoCase option for non-regex pattern '-f' is not supported and will be ignored.` in the apache error log (the docs also mention that NC is not valid here). OTOH, I do see the potential need for it. Do you think there is another solution for this NoCase-scenario? (Btw: my answer is also case sensitive for the `-f` check)

Comment: Yes that's true `NC` after `RewriteCond` is redundant but most of the filesystems ignore case anyway for filenames like on Windows, MAC etc

Comment: Actually, OP uses Apache (hence the .htaccess), which runs >60% on Linux (case sensitive) and ~20% on Windows (case insensitive). Mac is only ~1%. Therefore, `NC` in the -f condition is not redundant. If `File.htm` exists but `file.htm` is requested, I get `file.html` (redirect) on most Apache servers. However, OP did not request case insensitivity, so he can accept your answer...

Comment: This is an amazing trick, using the `$1` in the `RewriteCond` "backwards" from the matching in the `RewriteRule`! When using this, the redirect was exposing my document root (/var/www/...) to the browser, and causing 404. I changed `$1` on the last line to `/$1` to fix this. Thanks!

Comment: Yes indeed if `RewriteBase` is not used then we need to use `/$1`. Glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.htm$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.
RewriteRule ^(.+?)(?:\.htm|\.php)?$ $1.html [NC,L,R]
```

(`RewriteEngine On` is indeed needed here, but you know that already).

First, just check whether the requested file even exists. If not, then check whether the file ends in `.htm` OR `.php` OR does not have a point in it at all. If the conditions are met, apply the rule:

Any file that starts with `name` and then has either the extension `.htm` or `.php` or none at all (that's what the question mark is for) should be translated into `name.html`. And it should be the final rule (`L` flag).

All other files are left as is.

I also added the No Case (`NC`) flag, ignoring the case of the file. You may omit that if you prefer.

**Edit:** make the file name part greedy and valid only for at least one char (`+?` instead of `*`).

Comment: But it will redirect any `foobar.php` to `foobar.html` without checking existence of `html` file

Comment: I now see in OP's question the phrase 'and the latter does', which I didn't see earlier, my bad.